# Is there a price field that can be used to charge a percentage as a service fee in a priceset?

Tags: civievent

In order to add a service fee to prices, one could just add it to the base charge, e.g. if a fee is $20, just charge $20.80 for a 4% fee; but is there a way to add a fee whose value is based on another one? I suspect not, but wanted to check; otherwise it would need to be a custom mod.

Answer (score 1):

Should have looked before leaping - there's an extension named Percentage Price Field. As long as it works, that should work!

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you’re on Drupal is to use Webform CiviCRM module in combination with Webform Calculator module. You can then calculate Payment Processing Fees and add them as a line item.